# Is there a way to use chunksOf without creating nested lists?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use the chunksOf function to map a function onto two items at a time in a current list so for example.

```
newMerk <- map (\[x, y] -> createNode x y) . chuncksOf 2 $ mrk
```

and lets say we have a list [x, y, z, d, f, g, h, s, t, q] I would like this to work out so it looks like this after. [xy, zd, fg, hs, tq] instead of [[xy], [zd], [fg], [hs], [tq]]

Comment: To me, this sounds like a problem with `createNode`, not a problem with `chunksOf`. Perhaps you'd better follow the usual advice: include enough code that we can reproduce your problem -- and be sure to say exactly what the problem is (e.g. use a concrete list that we can type into ghci rather than a schematic list like `[x,y,z,d,f,g,h,s,t,q]` together with the concrete output you expect).

Comment: I agree with @DanielWagner. May be you should modify your createNode or create a helper function to intermediate between your list and your createNode function. It depends on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since `chunksOf` is able to produce dynamically sized chunks (ie. the size of the chunk depends on the `Int` argument which is only known at runtime), it must return a list. A regular tuple cannot work because tuples in Haskell have fixed, static length.

As for this specific problem, you can use a pairing function instead of `chunksOf`:

```
pair :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pair = liftM2 zip odds evens
```

where `odds` and `evens` respectively pick the odd and even ordinal elements. Then your example is simply

```
newMerk <- map (uncurry createNode) (pair mrk)
```

For extra *Fun*™, you could try to write a function along these lines:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamiles #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

type family Tuple (n :: Nat) a where
    Tuple 1 a = a
    Tuple 2 a = (a, a)
    Tuple 3 a = (a, a, a)
    Tuple 4 a = (a, a, a, a)
    ...

chunksOf :: KnownNat n => Proxy n -> [a] -> [Tuple n a]
chunksOf p xs = ???
```

But this seems like a lot more trouble than it's worth. I'm not even sure how to implement such a function with the dependently-typed tools available in current GHC and I expect writing a function to consume `[Tuple n a]` would be a headache as well.

Comment: +1 for the pair function. I love the simplicity and effectiveness, though I don't know about its performance.

Comment: As implemented here, `pair` is not an efficient function, to be sure. But for this example it's nicely illustrative :)

Answer (score 0):

Use tuples instead.

```
newMerk <- map (\[x, y] -> createNode x y) . chuncksOf 2 $ mrk
```

is a bad idea because `[x,y]` could fail to match. `chunksOf` will eventually spit back a list with one element if `mrk` has an odd number of elements. So you should try to make `mrk` a list of tuples instead.

> [x, y, z, d, f, g, h, s, t, q] I would like this to work out so it looks like this after. [xy, zd, fg, hs, tq] instead of [[xy], [zd], [fg], [hs], [tq]]

This doesn't make sense in general. If you can concatenate the elements of the list, you could use `fmap mconcat`, but I don't think that's the case here. Instead, construct the list to contain tuples by default.